# Wrong char value in C

Tags: c, char, int

Need some help in the last part of this function:

```
char *lfsr(char *bin)
{
    //bits significativos para fazer o xor 128 -> 128,126,101,99;
    int bits[4];
    int bit;

    if(bin[0] == '0')
        bits[0] = 0;
    else if(bin[0] == '1')
        bits[0] = 1;

    if(bin[2] == '0')
        bits[1] = 0;
    else if(bin[2] == '1')
        bits[1] = 1;

    if(bin[21] == '0')
        bits[2] = 0;
    else if(bin[21] == '1')
        bits[2] = 1;

    if(bin[19] == '0')
        bits[3] = 0;
    else if(bin[19] == '1')
        bits[3] = 1;

    bit = bits[0] ^ bits[1] ^ bits[2] ^ bits[3] ^ 1;
    //reconstruir o vector de char depois do lfsr
    for(int i = 127; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        bin[i] = bin[i - 1];
    }
    bin[0] = (int)bit;

    return bin;
}
```

Why the value of `bin[0]` is a strange character instead 0 or 1?
Anyone can help me please?
Thanks in advance. Cumps!

Comment: Depends on what you have stored in bin.

Comment: i have a char array with 0's and 1's, representing 128bit binary number

Comment: Print the "bin" contents before passing it to "lfsr".

Comment: What are you expecting to be in `bin[0]`? `'0'/'1'` or `0/1`? What is the value you're seeing if you print it as a number?

Comment: everything is working fine.. the only exception is bin[0].. when i print it i get a tiny smile..

Comment: i expect '0' or '1'. i want to convert bit variable into char and save it into bin[0].. the bit is always 0/1

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  What "strange character" is bin[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is character `'0'` and integer `0` being different. character `'0'` is actually the ascii value 48.

try `bin[0] = (char)(48 + bit);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably one of your if-elses didn't work.
Either bin[0], bin[2], bin[21] or bin[19] is neither '0', nor '1'.
Try running this code with your test data:

```
char *lfsr(char *bin)
{
    //bits significativos para fazer o xor 128 -> 128,126,101,99;
    int bits[4];
    int bit;

    if(bin[0] == '0')
        bits[0] = 0;
    else 
    {
        if(bin[0] == '1')
            bits[0] = 1;
        else
            printf("First if-else failed. bin[0] : %c\n", bin[0]);
    }

    if(bin[2] == '0')
        bits[1] = 0;
    else
    {
        if(bin[2] == '1')
            bits[1] = 1;
        else
            printf("Second if-else failed. bin[2] : %c\n", bin[2]);
    }

    if(bin[21] == '0')
        bits[2] = 0;
    else
    {
        if(bin[21] == '1')
            bits[2] = 1;
        else
            printf("Third if-else failed. bin[21] : %c\n", bin[21]);
    }

    if(bin[19] == '0')
        bits[3] = 0;
    else
    {
        if(bin[19] == '1')
           bits[3] = 1;
        else
            printf("Fourth if-else failed. bin[19] : %c\n", bin[19]);
    }

    bit = bits[0] ^ bits[1] ^ bits[2] ^ bits[3] ^ 1;
    //reconstruir o vector de char depois do lfsr
    for(int i = 127; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        bin[i] = bin[i - 1];
    }
    bin[0] = (int)bit;

    return bin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C language psychic and my crystal ball tells me that somewhere in your program you did this:

```
 printf("the value in bit[0] is %c\n", bit[0]);
```

Comment: nop.. try another crystal ball.. lfsr(binArray);
 printf("\n%s\n", binArray);